# conjugacy of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be a finite field of prime order $p$, and $M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ act on $M_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ by conjugacy action. Let $[A], [B]$ be two distinct conjugacy classes, and let $C \in [A]$ and $D \in [B]$. Does there is a $single$ matrix $P$ such that $C = P A P^{-1}$ and $D = P B P^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. In $M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$, let $A = C = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, let $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $D = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The only matrix conjugating $A$ to $C$ is the identity, which doesn't take $B$ to $D$. However, $B$ and $D$ are conjugate by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: (Maybe speaking a bit more abstractly: taking the case $A=C$, the question is asking if the stabilizer of $A$ acts transitively on all the other orbits of the action. You just need to find an $A$ whose orbit is too big (hence stabilizer is too small) for this to be possible. Most choices will do.)

Comment: I was trying to understand the feasibility of the statement: if A = B + C then [A] = [B] + [C], where the [.] denotes conjugacy class. One direction is easy [A] \subset [B] + [C].